# Direct3D 11 initialization and render sections

Tags: directx, direct3d

I got a simple Direct3D program running from an example in a book. It creates first a win 32 window and then a blank Direct3D scene. I am trying to completely re-jig the code so it is more modular and in a style I am more comfortable with.

Right now it is crashing when I call my `Render` function. The function is:

```
void Render(void)
{

    float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f };
    d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);
    swapChain_->Present(0, 0);

}
```

The wWinMain function is as follows:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
InitWindow();

InitD3D();

InitScene();

while (!progFinished)
{

    MessagePump(); 

    Render(); 
}
return 0;
}
```

As far as I can see it is crashing when it hits the `d3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);` The original code has the render function as:

```
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
{
    if( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
    else
    {
    // Update and Draw
    demo->Update( 0.0f ); 
    demo->Render( ); 
    }
}
```

where I have taken the needed components out of the demo header and implementation file.
I think I just do not fully understand where the DirectX 'information' is that allows it to continue the display procedure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *" it is crashing"* - so what is the error message and what does the debugger say? If you put a breakpoint on the `Render` function and step through line by line, are all your variables correctly initialised?

Comment: Ahh that was very helpful thanks. I see now that I am getting that error where you try and read from a NULL pointer. In the demo code they create a demo object but I haven't done anything like that. Thanks

Comment: I have been looking into this and still cant figure out the problem. It seems that in 'd3dContext_->ClearRenderTargetView(backBufferTarget_, clearColor);' the backBufferTarget_ has a value of 0x000.. When I remove it up to the InitD3D area, then my swapChain_ has a value of 0X000. It seems like after I have initialized D3d my program doesn't remember I've set it up. But I am pretty sure that from examples I have found online they do it a similar way and it works. Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: Are you checking the HRESULTs of your Create* calls?  A COM pointer set to NULL (0x000...) generally means creation failed.

Comment: You are right, I was not checking the initialization of each particular area of the setting up DirectX module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this for the answer. The problem was in an area of code I did not present:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowA("DX11BookWindowClass", "Blank Win32 Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

HWND was previously defined as global, then locally again here. All I had to do was remove `HWND` and it worked.

Thanks